# A root-find algorithm for the first-zero of a discontinuous function?

Tags: algorithms, roots, finance, searching

I'm working on a problem at work that requires me to search for the first date (x) that a financial model returns a value greater than zero (y>0).

Our current approach is simple. Start a guess-and-check several periods before an reasonably educated guess would expect y to be greater than 0. After that, we step 1 period at a time forward until be pass our threshold (y>0).

This financial model takes significant time to run, so each individual guess is costly and we'd like to improve our search speed by implementing a more intelligent approach.

The problem:

- the results are discontinuous
- the result (y) may go above and below zero many times within the search region
- the result may go above and below zero from one period to the next.
- we need to find the first occurrence of this happening, not just any f(x)=0

For all these reasons, basic search algorithms (Ridders, Secant, Bisection, etc) can't help us.

So my basic question: Is there a root-find algorithm for discontinuous functions? ideally one that searches for the first instance of a zero within a bracketed region?

Comment: A discontinuous function can be modelled by a continuous function. It's hard to advise without understanding your model.

Comment: The most extreme example that would be easy to describe would be trying to find the first time a stock went over a certain price on a given day... But you don't know the shape of the price chart that day, and discovering the stock price at any given time is costly so we want to minimize how many times we are asking that question.

Comment: As $f$ is not continuous, You can never exclude that $f(x)<$ for all $x$ but one. No matter what strategy you use, it is always possible that the only positive value occurs  for the last $x$ you test.

Comment: Is your function actually discontinuous or is it stochastic? Can you show something like a plot of your function? How are you sure you are finding the first zero right now and not just an arbitrary zero? How is the first zero important? These might help people answer your question, right now you haven't given enough information for anyone to give you an actual answer.